Is there a way to change the path to the .env file?
I used to have the following project structure:
| *other files.py*
| main.py
| .env

Then, I decided to sort the files into directories. The structure turned out to be as follows:
| src
| ∟ *other files.py*
| | main.py
| | .env

Everything worked before that. After that, when I try to get an environment variable, I get None. If you return .env to the directory above, as it was before, everything works again.
Is there a way to change the path to the .env file without decouple?
I rescheduled .env the file to another folder and would like to receive a variable, not None.

Are you using python-dotenv?

@mrconcerned yes.

I have submitted the answer, please let me know if it solves the issue, if not please add more information.

If you are using python-dotenv, you can manually specify the path to the .env file in your main.py or wherever you're loading environment variables.
Assuming your new structure looks like this:
src/
├── main.py
├── .env
└── other_files.py


You can load the .env file in your main.py like this:
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

# Specify the full path to your .env file in the src directory
env_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

# Now, you can access environment variables as usual
my_var = os.getenv('MY_ENV_VARIABLE')

print(my_var)  # This should not return None if the variable is correctly set in .env

where .env file would have
MY_ENV_VARIABLE=some_value

